# 3d plot in R - Patch

Tags: r, matlab, 3d, lattice, wireframe

I have the following data in a data frame:

```
**x** in (0,1)
**y** in [0,1]
**z** in [0,1]
```

For example:

```
X,Y,Z
0.1, 0.2, 0.56
0.1, 0.3, 0.57
...
```

I'd like to plot them on this type of chart:
[image: A 3d plot]

I tried on R, but all I could get was a [not-so-fancy 3d scatterplot](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/s3d2.png).
I also read about the [lattice 3d wireframe](https://web.archive.org/web/20100331095630/http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISpersonnel/lecoutre/stats/fichiers/_gallery.pdf), but I couldn't get my head around it.

What am I supposed to do to get a Matlab like wireframe in R?
What data transforms are involved?

This is the sample code from the documentation:

```
x <- seq(-pi, pi, len = 20)
y <- seq(-pi, pi, len = 20)
g <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
g$z <- sin(sqrt(g$x^2 + g$y^2))
wireframe(z ~ x * y, g, drape = TRUE,
aspect = c(3,1), colorkey = TRUE)
```

I don't find it particularly clear.

**EDIT**: the `persp3d` function works fine, and I was able to generate a 3d plot with one colour. How can I set a colour scale relative to the z value?

Thanks for any hints,
Mulone

Comment: It is  true that it takes a little practice to convert (x,y,z) data into a matrix of z-values for wireframe or other 3-d grid plotting tools. It's worth the effort to learn to convert, since once you know how, you never forget :-) .   You might like the scatterplot3d package, which does allow wiregrid plots.

Comment: This is untested so it's going as a comment rather than an answer.  I would recommend `with(mydata,persp(x=sort(unique(X)),y=sort(unique(Y)),z=matrix(Z,ncol=length(unique(x)))))` -- I'm not quite sure I got the matrix organized in the right order (maybe `byrow=TRUE` etc.)

Comment: See `example(wireframe)` and `example(persp)` and check if it fits your needs.

Comment: I never quite found the time to get my head around this, but look at the code here: http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/graphcode.php?graph=23

Answer (score 15):

Use `outer` to create the z values and then use `persp` to plot:

```
z <- outer(x,y, function(x,y) sin(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))
persp(x,y,z)
```

[image: persp]

There are options for colouring and setting the viewing angle, see `?persp`. See the fourth example for Matlab style colouring.

For an interactive plot, consider using `persp3d` in the `rgl` package:

```
require(rgl)
persp3d(x,y,z,col="blue")
```

**Edit**

To add colour, there is a slight difference from the method in `persp`, since the colour relates to the vertex rather than the centre of the facet, but it makes it easier.

```
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") ) 
pal <- jet.colors(100)
col.ind <- cut(z,100) # colour indices of each point
persp3d(x,y,z,col=pal[col.ind])
```

[image: persp3d]

The help file recommends adding the parameter `smooth=FALSE`, but that's down to personal preference.

Comment: The problem w/ this answer is it assumes z = f(x,y).  The OP said he had a set of ordered triples (x,y,z), in which case he'd need to generate a fitting function. Of course that will not plot the exact original data .

Comment: @Mulone I've included the example of adding height-based colouring to the `persp3d` plot.