# Visualize a function using double integration in R - Wacky Result

Tags: r, vectorization, probability, curve, integrate

I am trying to visualize a curve for pollination distribution.  I am very new to R so please don't be upset by my stupidity.

```
llim <- 0
ulim <- 6.29

f <- function(x,y) {(.156812/((2*pi)*(.000005^2)*(gamma(2/.156812)))*exp(-((sqrt(x^2+y^2))/.000005)^.156812))}

integrate(function(y) {
     sapply(y, function(y) {
          integrate(function(x) f(x,y), llim, ulim)$value
          })
     }, llim, ulim)

fv <- Vectorize(f)

curve(fv, from=0, to=1000)
```

And I get:

```
Error in y^2 : 'y' is missing
```

Comment: `curve` expects only a one-dimensional function

Comment: If this is not possible in R, I have Matlab and Mathematica as well, but I do not know how to code in either of them (at all).  Thank you again!!!

Comment: Thank you James.  Is there another command that I can use to plot this?

Comment: You probably want `persp`.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7568356/269476

Comment: It is certainly possible in R. However, can you better explain precisely what you want on your x-axis and y-axis?

Comment: I am hoping for Distance from 0 to 1000 meters on my x axis and the probability of pollination (or probability density) on my y axis.  I'm glad to hear it is possible in R!  I have looked up persp and tried to download it, but apparently do not have the correct version of R for that?  I can't find which version I need.  I have 2.14.1, 2.14.2, and 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking to plot. But I know you want to visualise your scalar function of two arguments.

Here are some approaches. First we define your function.

```
llim <- 0
ulim <- 6.29

f <- function(x,y) {
  (.156812/((2*pi)*(.000005^2)*(gamma(2/.156812)))*exp(-((sqrt(x^2+y^2))/.000005)^.156812))
}
```

From your title I thought of the following. The function defined below `intf` integrates your function over the square [0,ul] x [0,ul] and return the value. We then vectorise and plot the integral over the square as a function the length of the side of the square.

```
intf <- function(ul) {
  integrate(function(y) {
    sapply(y, function(y) {
      integrate(function(x) f(x,y), 0, ul)$value
      })
    }, 0, ul)$value
}
fv <- Vectorize(intf)
curve(fv, from=0, to=1000)
```

[image: Imgur]

If f is a distribution, I guess you can make your (somewhat) nice probability interpretation of this curve. (I.e. ~20 % probability of pollination(?) in the 200 by 200 meter square.)

However, you can also do a contour plot (of the log-transformed values) which illustrate the function we are integrating above:

```
 logf <- function(x, y) log(f(x, y))
 x <- y <- seq(llim, ulim, length.out = 100)
 contour(x, y, outer(x, y, logf), lwd = 2, drawlabels = FALSE)
```

[image: Imgur]

You can also plot some profiles of the surface:

```
plot(1, xlim = c(llim, ulim), ylim = c(0, 0.005), xlab = "x", ylab = "f")
y <- seq(llim, ulim, length.out = 6)
for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  tmp <- function(x) f(x, y = y[i])
  curve(tmp, llim, ulim, add = TRUE, col = i)
}
legend("topright", lty = 1, col = seq_along(y),
       legend = as.expression(paste("y = ",y)))
```

[image: Imgur]

They need to be modified a bit to make them publication worthy, but you get the idea. Lastly, you can do some 3d plots as others have suggested.

**EDIT**
As per your comments, you can also do something like this:

```
# Define the function times radius (this time with general a and b)
# The default of a and b is as before
g <- function(z, a = 5e-6, b = .156812) {
  z * (b/(2*pi*a^2*gamma(2/b)))*exp(-(z/a)^b)
}

# A function that integrates g from 0 to Z and rotates
# As g is not dependent on the angle we just multiply by 2pi
intg <- function(Z, ...) {
  2*pi*integrate(g, 0, Z, ...)$value
}

# Vectorize the Z argument of intg
gv <- Vectorize(intg, "Z")

# Plot
Z <- seq(0, 1000, length.out = 100) 
plot(Z, gv(Z), type = "l", lwd = 2)
lines(Z, gv(Z, a = 5e-5),         col = "blue", lwd = 2)
lines(Z, gv(Z, b = .150),         col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(Z, gv(Z, a = 1e-4, b = .2), col = "orange", lwd = 2)
```

[image: Imgur]

You can then plot the curves for the `a` and `b` you want. If either is not specified, the default is used.
Disclaimer: my calculus is rusty and I just did off this top of my head. You should verify that I've done the rotation of the function around the axis properly.

Comment: Okay, one more thing you might be able to help me with since you are currently my hero.  I am trying to visualize a graph of the cumulative fraction of pollen collected within a circle of radius Z (centered on the maternal parent) by integrating: (b/2pia^2(gamma(2/b))*exp(-(z/a)^b) from theta=0 to theta=2pi and z=0 to z=Z (where Z is the radius of the circle within which the cumulative fraction of pollen has been collected ie. pollination has occurred).  a is the scale parameter, b is the shape parameter and z is the sqrt(x^2+y^2).

Comment: @AndiNoakes I've edited my answer. Is that what you want? Please do check the maths yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `lattice` package has several functions that can help you draw 3 dimensional plots, including `wireframe()` and `persp()`.  If you prefer not to use a 3d-plot, you can create a contour plot using `contour()`.

Note: I don't know if this is intentional, but your data produces a very large spike in one corner of the plot. This produces a plot that is for all intents flat, with a barely noticable spike in one corner.  This is particularly problematic with the contour plot below.

```
library(lattice)

x <- seq(0, 1000, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(0, 1000, length.out = 50)
```

First the wire frame plot:

```
df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
df$z <- with(df, f(x, y))
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data = df)
```

[image]

Next the perspective plot:

```
dm <- outer(x, y, FUN=f)
persp(x, y, dm)
```

[image]

The contour plot:

```
contour(x, y, dm)
```

[image]

Comment: Contour plots are usually preferable to other 3D plots.

Comment: I should specify that I am just looking for a 2D curve though which shows leptokurtosis of pollen distribution.