# Get grid on the surface of a persp3d chart in R

Tags: r, charts

I was searching SO to find out how to draw matlab-like surface plots in R, and I found this page:

[3d plot in R - Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568356/3d-plot-in-r-patch)

I would like to use persp3d rather than persp, because of its interactive features, but persp by default has those lines of constant x and y on the surface (what would be called lines of longitude and latitude on a sphere) which I like, whereas I can't find any way to get the same using persp3d.

Is this feature available in persp3d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `surface3d` two times after you first call `persp3d` to add additional elements to the plot:

```
library(rgl)

x <- seq(-pi, pi, len = 20)
y <- seq(-pi, pi, len = 20)
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))) 

persp3d(x, y, z, col = "blue")
surface3d(x, y, z, back = "lines")
surface3d(x, y, z, front = "lines")
```

[image: 3D Plot]

Comment: Using RStudio 1.0.153 on macOS, rotating the model with the mouse causes a lot of visual flickering on the surfaces. How can this be remedied?